# How to manage mongodb connection using mongoengine django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, connection

I am running a `django` project and using `mongoengine` as my ORM for MongoDB. The project uses `daemons`, `celery`, `crons` and calling django custom commands which are using the django project and stores massive data in the database (MongoDB Atlas).

Here's my `settings.py` file where I'm building the `mongodb` connection using `mongoengine`

```py
CONNECTION_STRING = 'mongodb://{user}:{pwd}@{host}/{db}?replicaSet={replicaset}&ssl={ssl}&authSource={auth_source}'.format(
    user=env('DB_USERNAME'), pwd=env('DB_PASSWORD'), host=env('DB_HOST'), db=env('DB_DATABASE'), replicaset=env.str('DB_REPLICASET'), ssl=env.str('DB_SSL'), auth_source=env.str('DB_AUTH_SOURCE')
)

DB_CONNECTION = mongoengine.connect(host=CONNECTION_STRING, connect=False)
```

Suddenly I'm gettig alerts from MongoDb Atlas that connections have been overused. And I'm not sure how to handle connections in an optimised way or my existing settings are already optimised?

Below is the screenshot which shows 450+ connections always open.

[image]
Do I have to close the connection in every request class? any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Django then why do you use another ORM like MongoEngine? Django comes with its own ORM which you can connect to MongoDB using a [connector like djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @DanielCrisp no, but I merge the single writing calls and created batch calls with multiple write operations in one query and that's how I handled it.